# Ubuntu 14.04 recognize my Thunderbolt Ethernet only in start up

Tags: 14.04, ethernet, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

Ubuntu 14.04 recognize my Thunderbolt Ethernet only in start up and when Ethernet disconnect or unplug Thunderbolt Ethernet, i can not connect to Ethernet network any more and i have to restart. how can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. There maybe will be Hotplug Support in Ubuntu 15.04 , but today you can just reboot.

Lets hope this feature makes it to the release ;-)